# Can not get Ubuntu to boot from USB. or even show up in the boot menu

Tags: boot, usb

I have a thinkpad T420 running windows 7 and it meets all the required specs to run ubuntu. I have download ubuntu. Formatted and upload Ubuntu with Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.1 onto a sandisk 32 gb usb. Followed both the directions on the website and followed a step by step video tutorial. I also did the same using rufus. I have gone into my BIOS setup menu page and under boot have moved both USB hdd and USB fdd to the top of the list and tried them both separately. I have been playing around with it for hours (googling the problem and trying to follow steps others have taken) and nothing has work. i am clearly missing something, i just can not figure out what it is. Every time i restart my computer, the only options i am presented with are, windows and recovery.

So if it helps. I tried out the usb on my brother thinkpad 410s and it works fine there. But no matter what i do i cant get it to show up on my t420.

EDIT: Also this is a refurbished thinkpad that i just got a couple days ago. maybe something is wrong with the computer itself? just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

use a window tool called rufus.exe it works well with all linux distros.
after writing to usb, restart your pc, enter boot menu and chooose the usb and all will run well.

use default bios settings. f12 for boot menu on thinkpad t420, i use the same

Comment: tried rufus.exe as well as Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.1. still nothing. I listed my current start up settings in the above comment.

Comment: Just to double check i am going to run rufus again. will update in a couple minutes.  oh and just to be safe here are the settings rufus is running under. Device- install ubuntu (F:), Capacity 29.22GB File system Fat32 Cluster Size 16 kilobytes New Volume label Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS amd64 Quick Format checked Create a bootable disk using IOS image checked and create extended label and icon files checked

Comment: Just reformatted by usb using rufus and then rebooted my computer. still nothing. it just opens to boot options and the only two options are windows or recovery.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off Quick boot and switch to UEFI boot mode, not legacy.

In quick boot mode USB drives are not detected.

If your Ubuntu installer is 64-bit, it should boot in UEFI mode with no problem.

Comment: There is not an option to turn "off" quick boot. The options are either quick boot or diagnostics. anyway i switched it to diagnostics on UEFI first, still did not work. Then tried it with diagnostics on legacy. also did not work. and yes it is a 64-bit. Tried it with quick boot on both. also did not work.

Comment: Try to turn off the computer, not just reboot. Then insert the USB stick and power on. Then test the bios for Ubuntu boot option.

Comment: Tried it. Still Nothing. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: actually when i select only UEFI, it always takes me to the boot menu but then only gives two options (instead of the three listed when i am on legacy), neither of which do anything but reload the boot menu. not sure if that gives any insight or not.